# Can't install Ubuntu 16.04 [executing grub-install /dev/sda failed]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So I know that this has been asked before but I've tried to do what other answers say and still won't work.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 into my new Dell Inspiron 3467 laptop alongside Windows 10 but it won't finish installing. I'm booting from a USB flash drive, all the installation process goes OK until the very end when a window will pop up saying:

```
executing grub-install/dev/sda failed this is a fatal error
```

It then goes saying that they will send a report with the bug and that's it, the window won't close and usually that's when I restart.

So far this is the list of what I've done to try and solve it:

1. Turned the Secure Boot off in the BIOS.
2. Installing it with manual partition (with /, /home, /swap partitions)
3. Installing it with manual partition but creating an EFI System Partition and indicating that the boot loader goes in it.

Comment: Is it possible that the last time you didn't shutdown Windows completely but hibernated? In this case Windows might still hold a lock on the partition.

Comment: No, last time I used Windows10 was to shrink the main partition so I could install ubuntu and I remember shutting down the computer.

Comment: Windows 10 does not shut down, it hibernates unless "Fast Startup" is disabled. also be sure you boot ubuntu in EFI mode.

Comment: I'm installing ubuntu after disabling Fast Startup, but could it be that? I mean, I was installing it in unallocated space.

Comment: Still won't work, same error appeared, and yes I'm booting it in UEFI mode.